# boost::serialization: overloading load_construct_data: no accessible constructor at all

Tags: c++, boost, new-operator, boost-serialization

so I'm using the boost::serialization library, and I'm trying to overide how a class is constructed, since it has no default constructor. This is [demonstrated here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors). To me it appears the function takes the `class* t` and then sets it to point to a newly constructed object. If i'm wrong, this is definately the source of my error.

However, the only way to construct my class is by using another classes `create()` function, meaning I need to stray from the code in the example (*this is stated in the boost::serialization namespace*): `::new(t)my_class(attribute);`

I tried simply calling the create function and setting `t` equal to the returned pointer, but this doesn't seem to work because right after the `load_construct_data function`, and in the `serialization function`, the given `myClass&` is not the same as what I set 't' to.

**How do I do whatever ::new(t) is doing so the object created using the create function follows through into the serialize/other functions?**

Comment: I think you mean proficient instead of sufficient, but you don't really need to state that anyway - it's implied from the tags.

Comment: Also, this question doesn't seem to revolve around `boost` - we just need to find an alternative to placement new for use with non-constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct referred to in your question (`new(t) my_class(attribute)`) is called "placement new". The way it work is that

1. `t` must already point to an allocated region of memory (placement new doesn't do allocation by default)
2. An instance of `my_class` is constructed at that memory location.

However, since in your case you can't use constructors, then using any form of `new` is out of the question. But there is an alternative (sort of).

Since placement new pretty much just overwrites a chunk memory, we can use a regular function which does the same with an already constructed object. Such a function is `memcpy`:

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

All `memcpy` does is perform a byte-wise copy of `num` bytes from the memory pointed to by `source` to the memory pointed to by `destination`.

So let's say you started with this code in the `load_construct_data`

```
my_class obj = other_class::create();
```

Then we can use the `memcpy` function to "move" the value at `obj` into the memory reference by `t`:

```
memcpy((void*)t, (void*)(&obj), sizeof(obj));
```

While there are some details about how this works with your particular class, such as whether a bit-wise copy is "good enough", this is the best I've got with what you've asked. The one problem I see is if the destructor releases resources, than the copy will may become invalid.

To account for the possible problems with destruction, you can write your own deep copying function:

```
void deepCopy( my_class * destination, const my_class * source );
```

which you call instead of `memcpy`.

*Note*: please tell me if I went astray with anything here. I don't currently have a machine to test code on.

Comment: Thank You SO MUCH, you are my savior after a week of frusteration!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of not having a default constructor, the use of load_construct_data and save_construct data actually permits the use of shared_ptr instances. In my view, there is no need to play around with memcpy and raw pointers. Thus you can just do something like the following

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

#include <memory>

class MyClass {
  public:
    explicit MyClass(std::string const &str) : m_str(str) {}
    MyClass() = delete;
    std::string str() const
    {
        return m_str;
    }
 private:
   std::string m_str;
};

namespace boost { namespace serialization {

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar,
                   MyClass const & myClass,
                   unsigned int const) 
    {
        auto str = myClass.str();
        ar & str;
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void save_construct_data(Archive &ar,
                             MyClass const * myClass,
                             unsigned int const)
    {
        auto str = myClass->str();
        ar << str;
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void load_construct_data(Archive &ar,
                             MyClass * myClass,
                             unsigned int const)
    {
        std::string archived;
        ar >> archived;
        ::new(myClass)MyClass(MyClass(archived));
    }
}
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myClass(new MyClass("hello!"));
    std::stringstream os;
    ::boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);
    oa << myClass;

    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myClassB;
    std::stringstream is;
    is.str(os.str());
    ::boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(is);
    ia >> myClassB;

    return 0;
}
```